# Is "groundbreaking" a positive word, a negative word, or a neutral word?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, tone

I recently encountered the following sentence:

> The women's movement of the 1970's spawned the groundbreaking and influential works of socialists and historians.

I was asked to analyze whether this sentence conveys a positive connotation or a neutral one.

As far as I can understand, "influence" can be positive or negative.

For example (positive):

> Many people were influenced by the speech given by Swami Vivekanand in Chicago.

For example (negative):

> His criminal moves were influenced by a character in a movie.

For example (neutral):

> We are influenced by our surroundings.

But if we consider the sentence in the question, what can we conclude about its tone? Does the word "groundbreaking" make it seem positive, negative, or neutral?

Comment: Hitler Was both Groundbreaking and Influential. 
Without the greater surrounding context, this sentence is neutral.

Comment: I haven't found a dictionary insisting that 'groundbreaking' be used for positive new ventures, but it's usually used for such.

Comment: @JonathanPiccirilli it would be a very brave person who described Hitler's actions as "groundbreaking".  I think this proves that groundbreaking carries an implication of positivity, even if that isn't stated in the literal description in the dictionary.

Comment: I dare say that both _groundbreaking_ and _influential_ are, except maybe in some in extreme contexts, usually seen as positive.

Comment: The terms *positive* and *negative* are useful in mathematics - but not much help anywhere else, is my considered judgement.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Many things associated with Hitler have been beneficial to subsequent generations of Germans. The launch of the "people's car" being one, the building of the first motorways in Europe another. He also completed the process of German unification by introducing things like a national police service. His downside was that he left the country a heap of rubble, and a reputation such that "a thousand years would pass and still this guilt of Germany would not be erased" (said by Hans Frank - defendant at Nuremburg, subsequently executed for war crimes.)

Comment: @WS2 I'm not disputing that Hitler achieved *some* positive things for his country.  Regardless, would you personally choose to describe Hitler as "groundbreaking" in a public forum?

Comment: @MaxWilliams: IIRC, the Nazis were the first to issue general smoking bans. I would describe the Nazi smoking ban as groundbreaking. That has nothing to do with whether I like Nazis, whether I like smoking, or whether I like smoking bans. Groundbreaking has everything to do with it being the first of its kind, which is objectively measurable.

Comment: @Flater I agree that's the dictionary definition, but for **most people** it also, rightly or wrongly, carries an implication of positive action, and of the actor themselves being a good, "groundbreaking", person.  Ultimately, language is as language does: one must be pragmatic.  So it's not true to say that it has "everything to do with it being the first of its kind, which is objectively measurable" - the situation is more complicated than that.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Well I happen to think that smoking bans are a very good thing, so I would have described the first of them as groundbreaking, even if it had been introduced by Genghis Khan. And I am not sure that I wouldn't describe the German *blitzkreig* tactics of 1940 as being a "groundbreaking development in mobile warfare". For that is what it was.

Comment: *Groundbreaking* doesn't have to be positive, but in my experience usually it is. More attention-grabbing, for me, is that frogs and the devil *spawn*.

Comment: There are enough errors in the basic use of the English language in this question that it should simply be closed until the OP can correct more basic matters than the connotation of "groundbreaking."

Comment: @Xanne you can suggest and I will update accordingly.

Comment: Define *positive word*, *negative word*, and *neutral word*. POB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English has two somewhat similar-looking adjectives that carry rather different (or at least distinct) meanings: *groundbreaking* and *earth-shattering*. Evidently, the former has less ambiguously positive connotations than the latter. *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011) has this entry for *groundbreaking* as an adjective:

> **groundbreaking** ... *adj.* **1.** Of, relating to, or being a ceremony of breaking ground [to begin a construction project]. **2.** Characterized by originality and innovation: *groundbreaking technology*.

And it has this entry for *earth-shattering*:

> **earth-shattering** *adj.* Earthshaking [which in turn is defined as "Of great consequence or importance"]

The underlying allusions are, in the case of *groundbreaking*, to breaking up and removing a patch of ground in order to begin construction on a new building (a largely positive occurrence, according to common sociopolitical thinking) and, in the case of *earth-shattering*, to tearing asunder the fabric of the earth as by a powerful earthquake (metaphorically a potentially positive thing, but in literal experience rarely so).

If your sentence had read

> The women's movement of the 1970's spawned the **earth-shattering** and influential works of socialists and historians.

you might argue that the author was asserting that the effects of the women's movement of the 1970s were indisputably powerful but that the author was not necessarily claiming that they were positive. However, the sentence

> The women's movement of the 1970's spawned the **groundbreaking** and influential works of socialists and historians.

(it seems to me) conveys a sense of laying the groundwork for something good and desirable. The strong implication of *groundbreaking* is "important in a fundamental and positive way."

Comment: This is a good point.  I think that earth-shattering tends to be an example of **hyperbole** -  it's certainly stronger than ground-breaking.  But, as you say it's a more neutral (less positive) variation of the same metaphor.